# Why am I having "Missing argument in printf at ..." in perl?

Tags: perl

I have perl code where am printing to file. I give the format

```
my $format = "%4d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d" . " %7.2f" x 9 . "\n";
```

because I am writing year month day hour minute second and 9 float values. Then I write to my output file as

```
printf $format, @data;        # print data on the screen
printf OUT $format, @data;    # print data into the file
```

Both of the above statements print, but always with a warning of "Missing argument in printf at (line number)".
What is the correct way of writing the formt and/or the printf. Please help.

Comment: How many elements in `@data`?

Comment: There are 9 elements

Comment: The format string you provided causes `printf` to expect 15. Did you mean `x 3` instead of `x 9`?

Comment: I was thinking I have to put six formats for the date and 9 for the 9 data values each one with 2 decimal places. Then how do I put it to write the 6 date values and 9 data values?

Comment: `printf $format, $Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S, @data;`?

Comment: Add in your code `use Data::Dumper;` at the top and `print Dumper(\@data);` before your `printf`. Add output of the `Dumper(\@data` to your question -- it will explain us what you have in `@data` array and how to handle the data.

Comment: Just to complete the discussion,print  Dumper(\@data) prints the nine data values, each quoted and all in sqaure brckets as $var1=["-99.","-99." , ... "-99."] but each value on a separate line. In this case I had all missing values (i.e. -99.). Thanks very much Polar Bear

Comment: Please don't add new questions to existing quesitons. Post a new quesiton. And show what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This signifies that the format string requires more values than are contained in `@data`.

```
$ perl -we'my @data = qw( a b c ); printf "%s %s %s\n", @data;'
a b c

$ perl -we'my @data = qw( a b   ); printf "%s %s %s\n", @data;'
Missing argument in printf at -e line 1.
a b
```

In your case, the format string has 15 placeholders, but `@data` contains fewer than 15 elements.

---

Based on your comments, I think you want

```
printf $format, $Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S, @data;
```

This could also be written as follows:

```
my $ts = sprintf("%04-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S);
my $format = "%s".( " %7.2f" x 9 )."\n";
printf $format, $ts, @data;
```

Most of time, you'll start with a epoch timestamp (as returned by `time()`). In that situation, one could use the following:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $ts = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(time()));
my $format = "%s".( " %7.2f" x 9 )."\n";
printf $format, $ts, @data;
```

(Note that local times without an time zone offset creates ambiguous timestamps during "fall back" to standard time in areas with daylight-saving time.)

Comment: Help me to understand, the date is attached to the data, i.e. it is read from a file with the data. Then the data is split from the data but they are written together. So my understanding is that I can write printf  "($Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S).( " %7.2f" x 9 , @data)"\n";

Comment: You could do that, but you don't want to for two reasons. 1) The format string is a form of code, and injecting data into code is dangerous. It works out here, but it'll fail if the data contains `%`. This is called a code injection bug/flaw. That's why I used `%s` and passed the timestamp as a parameter. 2) It won't add the leading zeroes or spaces to month, day, hour, minute and second values less than 10 like you seem to want.

Comment: I think am defeated. This is what I have put in: my ($Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S, @data) = split ' ';  my $ts = sprintf("%04-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S);
        my $format = "%s".( " %7.2f" x 9 )."\n"; printf $format, $ts, @data; I am back to "Missing argument in printf at ..."

Comment: print 0+@data, "\n"; prints date and 7 values with Missing argument

Comment: Ikegami, actually the command block my ($Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S, @data) = split ' '; my $ts = sprintf("%04-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S); my $format = "%s".( " %7.2f" x 9 )."\n"; printf $format, $ts, @data; works. The problem of Invalid argument was coming from the fact that I left out d in %04. Thank you very much for solving my problem.

Comment: #ikegami, @Polar Bear are you there? Can you please help me with the edited question? Thank you for your understanding.