# having “Missing argument in printf at …” in perl?

Tags: perl

This is a repost of [Why am I having "Missing argument in printf at ..." in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565683/why-am-i-having-missing-argument-in-printf-at-in-perl). Though I accepted the answer, I am still having problems with printing. My original post was not well posed, as I should have included a data sample. I give an example below of the data I would like to rewrite. I have several files, each with a slightly different data format and data length. I give below data samples from two files. I have to remove the non-numeric characters and then print only the data.
The data has a header, which I would like to print as is.

```
Date;Time;Time zone;Wind Speed;Wind Direction;Battery Voltage;Temperature;Relative Humidity;Barometric Pressure;Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m²;Accumulated Total NRT;Wind Gust
2020-05-12;00:15;CAT;0.81;116.6;6.59;10.5;96.8;883.1;0.0;0.1;2.97
2020-05-12;00:30;CAT;2.18;39.1;6.59;10.3;97.3;883.1;0.0;0.1;4.34

Date    Time    Time zone   Dew point   Dew point_Unit  Dew point_Status    Temperature (MID)   Temperature (MID)_Unit  Temperature (MID)_Status    Temperature (MID)   Temperature (MID)_Unit  Temperature (MID)_Status    Temperature (MID)   Temperature (MID)_Unit  Temperature (MID)_Status    Precipitation (SUM) Precipitation (SUM)_Unit    Precipitation (SUM)_Status  Relative Humidity (AVG) Relative Humidity (AVG)_Unit    Relative Humidity (AVG)_Status
2020/05/11  23:45:00    CAT 12,4    °C  OK  17,9    °C  OK  17,9    °C  OK  17,9    °C  OK  0,0 mm  OK  100,0   % RH    OK
2020/05/12  00:00:00    CAT 12,4    °C  OK  17,9    °C  OK  17,9    °C  OK  17,9    °C  OK  0,0 mm  OK  100,0   % RH    OK
```

I really appreciate the efforts of those who helped me with my previous post, Ikegami, Polar Bear and others.

I will really appreciate any further help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw{strftime};
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Indent=1; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my $debug = 1;

my @now = localtime;
my $today = strftime('%Y%m%d', localtime(time -86400));

chdir $AWS_DataDirs or die "chdir failed on '$AWS_DataDirs': $! ($^E)";
for (my $jj=0; $jj < @AWS_Dirs; ++$jj)
{
 opendir my $in_dir, $AWS_Dirs[$jj] or die "opendir failed on $AWS_Dirs[$jj]: $! ($^E)";
 while (my $file=readdir $in_dir)              #reading input directory
 {
  next if -d $file;
  next unless $file =~ /$today/;
  if($file =~ /$today/)
  {
   open (IN, "< $AWS_Dirs[$jj]/$file") or die "open '$file': failed $! ($^E)";
   open (OUT, "> $Output_dir/$file_out[$jj]") or die "open '$file_out[$jj]': failed $! ($^E)";
   # copy the first line unchanged
   print OUT scalar(<IN>) for 1..1;
   while( <IN> )
   {
    chomp;
    s/\s+/ /g;                    # strip unneeded spaces before split
    s/[\-\:\;\°\*\%]/ /g;
    s/\// /g;
    s/MISSING/0./g;
    s/BAD/0./g;
    s/OK/ /g;
    s/[A-Za-z]/  /g;
    s/,/./g;
    my @data = split ' ';         # put read data in an array
    my $format = "%4d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d" . " %7.2f" x 12 . "\n";
    printf OUT $format, @data;    # print data into the file
   }
   close OUT;
  }
 }
 closedir $in_dir;
}


__END__
```

Comment: Show us the code that is not working.

Comment: It is not obvious from your question how the data should be printed out. First header is easy to parse, but with second header we have repeated columns 3 time related to temperature. Time present in first and second file have different formats -- which one should be used in the output -- `00:15` or `23:45:00`? Are you saying that all `Units` and `Status` fields can be omitted? First and second files have different _columns_ of data. Due different set of data they can not be combined into _one table_ and should be printed as different entities.

Comment: Your question is require significant clarification on final output -- should it be printed to terminal or into file(s)? Show us your take on the problem with some code to demonstrate some effort at the solution.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. I have provided the code. I have omitted the definition of directories to make the code a bit short. The situation is that there are different stations each in its own directory and for each day there is a file with the day's date as part of the name. The first line to be printed as is, no editing. The values to be printed just as a series, no titles on them. Data are written to a file. Each station with its own input and output files. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: As explained in your previous question, you have a printf format with more specifiers than arguments. You need to ensure that `@data` has one element for each specifier in the format. So, back up in your debugging and look at how you construct `@data`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Demonstration code for processing data file of first type.

**NOTE:** Some flexibility was added to allow select data columns of interest.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Read data 
my($columns,$data) = read_data();

# Three ways to output data
say_info($columns,$data);
say_table_v($columns,$data);
say_table_h($columns,$data);

# Select only columns of interest
my $sel_columns = [@{$columns}[0,1,2,3,4,11,6]];
say_info($sel_columns,$data);
say_table_v($sel_columns,$data);
say_table_h($sel_columns,$data);

#
# Read data
#
# NOTE:
#   Make change 
#       $header = <DATA>;   -- read from DATA block
#       $header = <>;       -- read from file or pipe
#
#       while(<DATA>) {     -- read from DATA block
#       while(<>) {         -- read from file or pipe
#
sub read_data {
    my($header,@columns,@data);

    $header = <DATA>;
    chomp $header;
    @columns = split(';', $header);

    # Obtain data
    while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        next if /^\s*$/;        # skip empty lines
        my %hash;
        @hash{@columns} = split(';',$_);
        push @data, \%hash;
    }

    return(\@columns,\@data);
}

# Simple output parameters : values
sub say_info {
    my $columns = shift;
    my $data   = shift;

    for my $record (@{$data}) {
        say '-- Record ' . '-' x 35;
        for my $column (@$columns) {
            printf "  %10s : %s\n", $record->{$column}, $column;
        }
    }
}

# Table with data placed vertically
sub say_table_v {
    my $columns = shift;
    my $data   = shift;

    my %hash;
    my $record_count;

    for my $record (@{$data}) {
        $record_count++;
        push @{$hash{$_}}, $record->{$_} for @$columns;
    }

    # Find widest header title
    my $width = 0;
    for (@$columns) {
        my $len = length($_);
        $len-- if /Pyranometer/;    # Compensate for m²
        $width = $len > $width ? $len : $width;
    }

    # Form format string
    my $format = "| %-${width}s |" . " %-10s |" x $record_count . "\n";
    my $h = '+' . '-' x ($width+2) . '+' . '------------+' x $record_count;

    my @header = ('Measurement');
    push @header, 'Value' while $record_count--;

    say $h;
    printf $format, @header;
    say $h;
    printf $format, $_, @{$hash{$_}} for @$columns;
    say $h;
}

# Table with data placed horizontally
sub say_table_h {
    my $columns = shift;
    my $data    = shift;

    my $format;
    my $div;

    # Form format string
    for my $column (@$columns) {
        my $len = length($column);
        $len = 10 if $column eq 'Date';             # Date width 10
        $len =  5 if $column eq 'Time';             # Time width 5
        $len--    if $column =~ /Pyranometer/;      # Due m²
        if ( $column =~ /Date|Time/ ) {
            $format .= sprintf "| %%-%ds ", $len;   # Left adjusted
        } else {
            $format .= sprintf "| %%%ds ", $len;    # Right adjusted
        }
        $div .= '+' . '-' x ($len+2);
    }

    $format .= "|\n";
    $div .= "+\n";

    print $div;
    printf $format, @$columns;
    print $div;

    for my $record (@{$data}) {
        printf $format, map { $record->{$_} } @$columns;
    }
    print $div;
}

__DATA__
Date;Time;Time zone;Wind Speed;Wind Direction;Battery Voltage;Temperature;Relative Humidity;Barometric Pressure;Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m²;Accumulated Total NRT;Wind Gust
2020-05-12;00:15;CAT;0.81;116.6;6.59;10.5;96.8;883.1;0.0;0.1;2.97
2020-05-12;00:30;CAT;2.18;39.1;6.59;10.3;97.3;883.1;0.0;0.1;4.34
2020-05-12;00:30;CAT;2.18;39.1;6.59;10.3;97.3;883.1;0.0;0.1;4.34
2020-05-12;00:30;CAT;2.18;39.1;6.59;10.3;97.3;883.1;0.0;0.1;4.34
```

Output

```
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:15 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        0.81 : Wind Speed
       116.6 : Wind Direction
        6.59 : Battery Voltage
        10.5 : Temperature
        96.8 : Relative Humidity
       883.1 : Barometric Pressure
         0.0 : Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m²
         0.1 : Accumulated Total NRT
        2.97 : Wind Gust
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:30 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        2.18 : Wind Speed
        39.1 : Wind Direction
        6.59 : Battery Voltage
        10.3 : Temperature
        97.3 : Relative Humidity
       883.1 : Barometric Pressure
         0.0 : Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m²
         0.1 : Accumulated Total NRT
        4.34 : Wind Gust
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:30 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        2.18 : Wind Speed
        39.1 : Wind Direction
        6.59 : Battery Voltage
        10.3 : Temperature
        97.3 : Relative Humidity
       883.1 : Barometric Pressure
         0.0 : Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m²
         0.1 : Accumulated Total NRT
        4.34 : Wind Gust
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:30 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        2.18 : Wind Speed
        39.1 : Wind Direction
        6.59 : Battery Voltage
        10.3 : Temperature
        97.3 : Relative Humidity
       883.1 : Barometric Pressure
         0.0 : Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m²
         0.1 : Accumulated Total NRT
        4.34 : Wind Gust
+---------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Measurement               | Value      | Value      | Value      | Value      |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Date                      | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-12 |
| Time                      | 00:15      | 00:30      | 00:30      | 00:30      |
| Time zone                 | CAT        | CAT        | CAT        | CAT        |
| Wind Speed                | 0.81       | 2.18       | 2.18       | 2.18       |
| Wind Direction            | 116.6      | 39.1       | 39.1       | 39.1       |
| Battery Voltage           | 6.59       | 6.59       | 6.59       | 6.59       |
| Temperature               | 10.5       | 10.3       | 10.3       | 10.3       |
| Relative Humidity         | 96.8       | 97.3       | 97.3       | 97.3       |
| Barometric Pressure       | 883.1      | 883.1      | 883.1      | 883.1      |
| Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m² | 0.0        | 0.0        | 0.0        | 0.0        |
| Accumulated Total NRT     | 0.1        | 0.1        | 0.1        | 0.1        |
| Wind Gust                 | 2.97       | 4.34       | 4.34       | 4.34       |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| Date       | Time  | Time zone | Wind Speed | Wind Direction | Battery Voltage | Temperature | Relative Humidity | Barometric Pressure | Pyranometer 0 - 2000 W/m² | Accumulated Total NRT | Wind Gust |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| 2020-05-12 | 00:15 | CAT       |       0.81 |          116.6 |            6.59 |        10.5 |              96.8 |               883.1 |                       0.0 |                   0.1 |      2.97 |
| 2020-05-12 | 00:30 | CAT       |       2.18 |           39.1 |            6.59 |        10.3 |              97.3 |               883.1 |                       0.0 |                   0.1 |      4.34 |
| 2020-05-12 | 00:30 | CAT       |       2.18 |           39.1 |            6.59 |        10.3 |              97.3 |               883.1 |                       0.0 |                   0.1 |      4.34 |
| 2020-05-12 | 00:30 | CAT       |       2.18 |           39.1 |            6.59 |        10.3 |              97.3 |               883.1 |                       0.0 |                   0.1 |      4.34 |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:15 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        0.81 : Wind Speed
       116.6 : Wind Direction
        2.97 : Wind Gust
        10.5 : Temperature
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:30 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        2.18 : Wind Speed
        39.1 : Wind Direction
        4.34 : Wind Gust
        10.3 : Temperature
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:30 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        2.18 : Wind Speed
        39.1 : Wind Direction
        4.34 : Wind Gust
        10.3 : Temperature
-- Record -----------------------------------
  2020-05-12 : Date
       00:30 : Time
         CAT : Time zone
        2.18 : Wind Speed
        39.1 : Wind Direction
        4.34 : Wind Gust
        10.3 : Temperature
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Measurement    | Value      | Value      | Value      | Value      |
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Date           | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-12 |
| Time           | 00:15      | 00:30      | 00:30      | 00:30      |
| Time zone      | CAT        | CAT        | CAT        | CAT        |
| Wind Speed     | 0.81       | 2.18       | 2.18       | 2.18       |
| Wind Direction | 116.6      | 39.1       | 39.1       | 39.1       |
| Wind Gust      | 2.97       | 4.34       | 4.34       | 4.34       |
| Temperature    | 10.5       | 10.3       | 10.3       | 10.3       |
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| Date       | Time  | Time zone | Wind Speed | Wind Direction | Wind Gust | Temperature |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| 2020-05-12 | 00:15 | CAT       |       0.81 |          116.6 |      2.97 |        10.5 |
| 2020-05-12 | 00:30 | CAT       |       2.18 |           39.1 |      4.34 |        10.3 |
| 2020-05-12 | 00:30 | CAT       |       2.18 |           39.1 |      4.34 |        10.3 |
| 2020-05-12 | 00:30 | CAT       |       2.18 |           39.1 |      4.34 |        10.3 |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Polar Bear. Could you kindly reformat the output for me so that the report for each time is on one line. I have to write the data for the whole day. Something like: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm value value ... value. I do not mind the variable names. It would suffice to have the first line of the data, so I can know what the variables are. The data samples I gave are from two different files, so they will be written to two different files. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba -- I've asked you for clarification of your question. Ideally you should add to your question desired output -- otherwise we can not read your mind. I did code what came to my mind in sense how  the output can look with data set at hand -- but my guess can be far fetched from what you desired to see.

Comment: Thanks infinitely @ Polar Bear. Excuse me for making you spend more time than necessary because of my imprecision. I apologize. The last table you have given as output is perfectly the way I want the output. however I do not need the lines in the table, because next I want to read the data with Fortran. This is far beyond the basic Perl that I know. So pardon me, if I may ask you to just compile the part of code that gives me your last table, including reading from a file. I am really grateful. I hope I am clear enough this time.

Comment: my apologies once more for being too demanding. I managed to run your code with my data and am able to print as required. Thank you very much for making me advance my Perl knowledge.